# How can I upload pictures and make those pictures have a permanent link in express js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Now I've done upload-part. It can just upload pictures. There is a problem, if I upload a file but not a picture, the website show me a []. Bascially I just want reject this upload. I am not sure what's going on. And how should I have a permanent link to the picture? 
Here is my code:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var multer = require('multer');
var upload = multer({
    dest: 'public/uploads/', fileFilter: function (req, file, cb) {
        if (file.mimetype !== 'image/png'
            && file.mimetype !== 'image/jpg'
            && file.mimetype !== 'image/jpeg'
            && file.mimetype !== 'image/gif') {
            console.log('wrong type')
            return cb(null, false, new Error('goes wrong on the mimetype'));
        }
        return cb(null, true);
    }
 });

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

router.post('/', upload.any(), function (req, res) {
    res.send(req.files);
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: In the fileinfo is the `mimetype`. Here you can only allow `image/png`, `image/jpeg` ...

Comment: Finally I got your point and do you know about permanent link?

Comment: Simply use a random string or a uuid. You only have to make suse that the image will be always accessable under a url with this string. e.g. `/images/uploads/3b052762054c480181138cf1fd138d3f.png`

Comment: For now I got "[{"fieldname":"myimage","originalname":"2012-07-16-259.jpg","encoding":"7bit","mimetype":"image/jpeg","destination":"public/uploads/","filename":"5e57c2ff3e6b8c087978d8004755599c","path":"public\\uploads\\5e57c2ff3e6b8c087978d8004755599c","size":25243}]
" if I uploaded a picture. Seems like the same thing you said.

Comment: multer automaticly creates an id for you (`filename`). If you want to use it and are serving `public` than you can simply access your picture over that path, or use a custom route to access it with another url.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to limit the number of images that can be uploaded then you need to use `.single(fieldname)` instead of `mutler.any()`

In the docs you can see what the difference is:

[mutler.any()](https://github.com/expressjs/multer#any):

> Accepts all files that comes over the wire. An array of files will be stored in `req.files`.

[mutler.single(fieldname)](https://github.com/expressjs/multer#singlefieldname)

> Accept a single file with the name `fieldname`. The single file will be stored in `req.file`.